# How can I perform an operation on two windowed DStreams with an offset?

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I'd like to compute the difference (by key) of two DStreams with different windows. This could be accomplished with a join. However, I want to have an offset between the DStreams. One way to do this would be to drop N windows of one of the DStreams, but I don't know how to do that either.